# Pagination Using ajax

Tags: ajax, pagination

I want to use Pagination using ajax for custom post taxonomy.
Many of codes are tried by me but at the last I was failed. So,how can i use pagination using ajax without plugin?

When i am clicking on load more button then the post will load on the same page.

**post name:- project**

**taxonomy name:- framework**

**`functions.php`**

```php
 function wp_pagination() {
    global $wp_query;
    $big = 12345678;
    $page_format = paginate_links(array(
        'base' => str_replace($big, '%#%', esc_url(get_pagenum_link($big))),
        'format' => '?paged=%#%',
        'current' => max(1, get_query_var('paged')),
        'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
        'type' => 'array'
            ));
    if (is_array($page_format)) {
        $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') == 0 ) ? 1 :
                get_query_var('paged');
        // echo '<div><ul>';
        // echo '<li><span>'. $paged . ' of ' . $wp_query->max_num_pages.'</span></li>';
        echo "<center>";
        foreach ($page_format as $page) {
            echo " " . $page;
        }
        echo "</center>";
        echo '</div>';
    }
}
```

Comment: How are we suppose to help you if you do not show us your code. There are so many good plugins out there which you can use as reference, or just simply use. IMHO, I do not see why do you not want to use a plugin if you cannot code such a project yourself

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had got the ans.

First you have to add following code in your function.php to call ajax in your template**

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_demo-pagination-load-posts', 'cvf_demo_pagination_load_posts' );

add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_demo-pagination-load-posts', 'cvf_demo_pagination_load_posts' ); 

function cvf_demo_pagination_load_posts() {

    global $wpdb;
    // Set default variables
    $msg = '';

    if(isset($_POST['page'])){
        // Sanitize the received page   
        $page = sanitize_text_field($_POST['page']);
        $cur_page = $page;
        $page -= 1;
        // Set the number of results to display
        $per_page = 3;
        $previous_btn = true;
        $next_btn = true;
        $first_btn = true;
        $last_btn = true;
        $start = $page * $per_page;

        // Set the table where we will be querying data
        $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "posts";

        // Query the necessary posts
        $all_blog_posts = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("
            SELECT * FROM " . $table_name . " WHERE post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish' ORDER BY post_date DESC LIMIT %d, %d", $start, $per_page ) );

        // At the same time, count the number of queried posts
        $count = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("
            SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM " . $table_name . " WHERE post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish'", array() ) );

        /**
         * Use WP_Query:
         *
        $all_blog_posts = new WP_Query(
            array(
                'post_type'         => 'post',
                'post_status '      => 'publish',
                'orderby'           => 'post_date',
                'order'             => 'DESC',
                'posts_per_page'    => $per_page,
                'offset'            => $start
            )
        );

        $count = new WP_Query(
            array(
                'post_type'         => 'post',
                'post_status '      => 'publish',
                'posts_per_page'    => -1
            )
        );
        */

        // Loop into all the posts
        foreach($all_blog_posts as $key => $post): 

            // Set the desired output into a variable
            $msg .= '
            <div class = "col-md-12">       
                <h2><a href="' . get_permalink($post->ID) . '">' . $post->post_title . '</a></h2>
                <p>' . $post->post_excerpt . '</p>
                <p>' . $post->post_content . '</p>
            </div>';

        endforeach;

        // Optional, wrap the output into a container
        $msg = "<div class='cvf-universal-content'>" . $msg . "</div><br class = 'clear' />";

        // This is where the magic happens
        $no_of_paginations = ceil($count / $per_page);

        if ($cur_page >= 7) {
            $start_loop = $cur_page - 3;
            if ($no_of_paginations > $cur_page + 3)
                $end_loop = $cur_page + 3;
            else if ($cur_page <= $no_of_paginations && $cur_page > $no_of_paginations - 6) {
                $start_loop = $no_of_paginations - 6;
                $end_loop = $no_of_paginations;
            } else {
                $end_loop = $no_of_paginations;
            }
        } else {
            $start_loop = 1;
            if ($no_of_paginations > 7)
                $end_loop = 7;
            else
                $end_loop = $no_of_paginations;
        }

        // Pagination Buttons logic     
        $pag_container .= "
        <div class='cvf-universal-pagination'>
            <ul>";

        if ($first_btn && $cur_page > 1) {
            $pag_container .= "<li p='1' class='active'>First</li>";
        } else if ($first_btn) {
            $pag_container .= "<li p='1' class='inactive'>First</li>";
        }

        if ($previous_btn && $cur_page > 1) {
            $pre = $cur_page - 1;
            $pag_container .= "<li p='$pre' class='active'>Previous</li>";
        } else if ($previous_btn) {
            $pag_container .= "<li class='inactive'>Previous</li>";
        }
        for ($i = $start_loop; $i <= $end_loop; $i++) {

            if ($cur_page == $i)
                $pag_container .= "<li p='$i' class = 'selected' >{$i}</li>";
            else
                $pag_container .= "<li p='$i' class='active'>{$i}</li>";
        }

        if ($next_btn && $cur_page < $no_of_paginations) {
            $nex = $cur_page + 1;
            $pag_container .= "<li p='$nex' class='active'>Next</li>";
        } else if ($next_btn) {
            $pag_container .= "<li class='inactive'>Next</li>";
        }

        if ($last_btn && $cur_page < $no_of_paginations) {
            $pag_container .= "<li p='$no_of_paginations' class='active'>Last</li>";
        } else if ($last_btn) {
            $pag_container .= "<li p='$no_of_paginations' class='inactive'>Last</li>";
        }

        $pag_container = $pag_container . "
            </ul>
        </div>";

        // We echo the final output
        echo 
        '<div class = "cvf-pagination-content">' . $msg . '</div>' . 
        '<div class = "cvf-pagination-nav">' . $pag_container . '</div>';

    }
    // Always exit to avoid further execution
    exit();}
```

Now add this following code where you want to display your post.(like,index.php,home.php,etc..)

```
<div class="col-md-12 content">
    <div class = "inner-box content no-right-margin darkviolet">
        <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            // This is required for AJAX to work on our page
            var ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>';

            function cvf_load_all_posts(page){
                // Start the transition
                $(".cvf_pag_loading").fadeIn().css('background','#ccc');

                // Data to receive from our server
                // the value in 'action' is the key that will be identified by the 'wp_ajax_' hook 
                var data = {
                    page: page,
                    action: "demo-pagination-load-posts"
                };

                // Send the data
                $.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
                    // If successful Append the data into our html container
                    $(".cvf_universal_container").append(response);
                    // End the transition
                    $(".cvf_pag_loading").css({'background':'none', 'transition':'all 1s ease-out'});
                });
            }

            // Load page 1 as the default
            cvf_load_all_posts(1);

            // Handle the clicks
            $('.cvf_universal_container .cvf-universal-pagination li.active').live('click',function(){
                var page = $(this).attr('p');
                cvf_load_all_posts(page);

            });

        }); 
        </script>
        <div class = "cvf_pag_loading">
            <div class = "cvf_universal_container">
                <div class="cvf-universal-content"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>      
</div>
```

And at the last put this code into your style.css

```
.cvf_pag_loading {padding: 20px;}
.cvf-universal-pagination ul {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
.cvf-universal-pagination ul li {display: inline; margin: 3px; padding: 4px 8px; background: #FFF; color: black; }
.cvf-universal-pagination ul li.active:hover {cursor: pointer; background: #1E8CBE; color: white; }
.cvf-universal-pagination ul li.inactive {background: #7E7E7E;}
.cvf-universal-pagination ul li.selected {background: #1E8CBE; color: white;}
```

At the last you will see like this.

[image]

Comment: Awesome answer!! Thank you!! With some improvements in the ajax part I managed to get this to work. I used only javascript, with no jQuery. Also, as Mohan said in the other answer, note that you need to replace older data with the new one, in my case I did `container.innerHTML = this.response;`

Comment: good answer but it is incomplete without click event of pagination number.

Answer (score 1):

I really appreciate the Pieter Goosen's efforts.

Its now appending every response to same element and not removing older data as its pagination not ajax load more..Make changed as per below :

```
//$(".cvf_universal_container").append(response);
$(".cvf_universal_container").empty().append(response);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using native `paginate_links()`** (but working around the links):

**your jQuery script**

```
jQuery( document ).on("click", ".page-numbers", function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 // prepare the number from "href" for ajax
 var formdata=$("#yourform").serialize() 
  + "&action=yourajaxaction&pagenum=" + this.attr("href").replace("#","");

 //do the ajax
 $.post( ajaxurl, formdata, function( response ) {
   $("#ajaxcont").html(response);
 });
```

**in your ajax function**

```
    // get the page number
    $args["paged"]=(int)$_POST["pagenum"];

    // ... process query with $args ...
    
    //output pagination 
    echo paginate_links( array(
        'total'        => $thaquery->max_num_pages,
        'current'      => $thaargs["paged"],
        'base' => "#%#%" //will make hrefs like "#3"
    ) );
```

Comment: Please update your code with explanation, or with html code, because it's not obvious what `$("#yourform")` is referencing, since there is no form made by the wp `paginate_links()`  And the same with `$("#ajaxcont")`, like what is that referencing? Plus `$thaquery` and `$thaargs` is not clear what that is either. So I'm not sure this is a full answer.